# How can I fix below issue when host blazor app to windows server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

When I upload my blazor app to windows server then getting below issue. I have tried different solution but could not get the success. If any body get the same issue and can help on this then that would be helpful.

Its working well in local but when I publish the blazor.server app and then upload or host to the server then getting this issue. It is in asp.net core 3.1.

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState
> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) <0x1c4b380 + 0x000b0> in :0
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache) <0x1c4b1b8 + 0x0001c> in :0
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x1c4b050 + 0x0002e> in :0
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) <0x1ca3880 + 0x00062> in :0
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) <0x1ca3840 + 0x0000a> in :0
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) <0x1ca3780 + 0x00006> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent (System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, System.Type componentType) <0x1ca3660 + 0x00006> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateComponent (System.Type componentType) <0x1ca26d8 + 0x00014> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeFrame& frame, System.Int32 parentComponentId) <0x1f5c1e0 + 0x0005c> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder+DiffContext& diffContext, System.Int32 frameIndex) <0x1f5c070 + 0x0004c> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder+DiffContext& diffContext, System.Int32 frameIndex) <0x1f5bdf0 + 0x0007a> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder+DiffContext& diffContext, System.Int32 newFrameIndex) <0x1f5bae8 + 0x000b4> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder+DiffContext& diffContext, System.Int32 oldStartIndex, System.Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, System.Int32 newStartIndex, System.Int32 newEndIndexExcl) <0x1f5af18 + 0x0048c> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer renderer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, System.Int32 componentId, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.ArrayRange`1[T] oldTree, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.ArrayRange`1[T] newTree) <0x1f59ff0 + 0x0008c> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment renderFragment) <0x1f53dd0 + 0x00100> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry) <0x1f518e0 + 0x0004c> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue () <0x1f51020 + 0x00092> in :0

Comment: You ought to include the version(s) here. Is this still on Core 3.x ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes it is in asp.net core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this, but it seems to me that disabling the linker will fix the issue...This is a temporary solution...for the correct solution consult the Blazor team

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I could not see this property anywhere in my project? Where can I find this?

Comment: I added this and it worked. Thanks. Why happened this? Can you please give some details?

Comment: @TusharMaru Blazor tries to minimize the size of the application by using the linker to trim out code it think's isn't being used. It does not always get it right. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/configure-linker?view=aspnetcore-3.1